# combination of rows of dataframe in R

Tags: r, data.table, combinations

I want to create a new dataframes such that

df1

```
A1 B1 C1
1  2  3
4  5  6
7  8  9
```

result_df

```
A1 B1 C1 A2 B2 C2
1  2  3  4  5  6
1  2  3  7  8  9
4  5  6  7  8  9
```

Basically, pairwise combination of rows such that row[i] != row [j]
I can do this using for loop. But I was wondering is there a way I can use data.table or apply function to make it faster.

Comment: Not sure why this has attracted so many downvotes. It's actually fairly tricky to get this right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's always numbers in your data frame then you can use the following

```
## Generate data
DF <- as.data.frame(matrix(1:9,3))
DF
  V1 V2 V3
1  1  4  7
2  2  5  8
3  3  6  9
```

Then combine the rows

```
t(apply(t(combn(3,2)), 1, FUN = function(x){unlist(DF[x])}))
```

which yields this matrix

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    2    3    4    5    6
[2,]    1    2    3    7    8    9
[3,]    4    5    6    7    8    9
```

If you need non-numeric columns in your data frame then the code above needs to be tweaked a bit.

**Update based on the comment below**

To make the input identical to the OP we just need to make sure that we extract rows instead of columns in the function call

```
DF <- as.data.frame(matrix(1:9,3,byrow=TRUE))
t(apply(t(combn(3,2)), 1, FUN = function(x){unlist(DF[x,])}))
```

which produces

```
     V11 V12 V21 V22 V31 V32
[1,]   1   4   2   5   3   6
[2,]   1   7   2   8   3   9
[3,]   4   7   5   8   6   9
```

The order becomes different but the result is the same.

Comment: Your example data is not the same as OP's. Try `DF <- as.data.frame(matrix(1:9,3,byrow=TRUE))`

Comment: Lol - hadn't noticed your comment until now. Better late than never

Answer (score 2):

A solution that won't force different columns to all be the same type:

```
DF <- as.data.frame(matrix(1:9,3,byrow=TRUE))

cmb <- combn(seq_len(nrow(DF)), 2)
cbind(DF[cmb[1,],], DF[cmb[2,],])

#    V1 V2 V3 V1 V2 V3
#1    1  2  3  4  5  6
#1.1  1  2  3  7  8  9
#2    4  5  6  7  8  9
```